# "Not all people HAVE/HAS pigments in their eyes"

Tags: negation, subject-verb-agreement

Should I use "have" or "has" after the word "people"?

For example:

> "Not all people **HAVE** pigments in their eyes"

or

> "Not all people **HAS** pigments in their eyes

I'm asking it because "people" refers to a quantity, it says more than one person, at least two.

Comment: The two questions (I guess *have vs. has* and *the vs. no the*) are different issues. They need to be asked in separate questions. You might also elaborate why you think either might be OK.

Comment: And then there's the question of whether _pigments_ should be plural or singular.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The first sentence with "have" is correct while the  second
   sentence with "has" isn't correct.  The word people is a plural noun 
   that takes the plural form of a verb.
2. Again, the first sentence with have is OK, whereas the second one isn't
   correct.

The difference between the two sentences  with "the people" and "people" is that we are referring to specific people in the former, at a party for example, whereas  we are making a general statement about people in the latter; it has a general meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**people** is used in plural third person. So you need to use **people have.**
For the second one: — *Not all people* (...).

Even though, I've seen this written as *Not all the people.* I guess it depends of the context.